# Synchronize system clock with UTC time using C uder Window OS

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have UTC time which is coming from UDP, I have a program to calculate Day and Time of UTC, how can I set my system clock at that day and time, kindly give me some direction so that I can make it possible.

I am using Window OS.

Comment: Can't windows do that already by itself?

Comment: It certainly does.  Messing up the clock drift compensation, not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the current system time, use the [`SetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API function.